# is there any way to get all pods in cluster without RBAC?

Tags: java, kubernetes

I looked at https://github.com/kubernetes-client/java library but it requires RBAC enabled in cluster. Is any other way to retrieve pods in kubernetes programatically?

Comment: That looks like the standard API client; it shouldn't specifically require an RBAC-enabled cluster.  `kubectl get pods --all-namespaces` should be able to do what you want and that translates pretty straightforwardly into the API.  Do you have a specific example that doesn't work?

Comment: `kubectl` works just fine. I'm looking for achieve the same programmatically. Official Kubernetes Java Client requires RBAC enabled.

Comment: where does it state that RBAC has to be enabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per Kubernetes Java Client library you can find there:

1. [InClusterClient](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/java/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/io/kubernetes/client/examples/KubeConfigFileClientExample.java) Example (Configure a client while running inside the Kubernetes cluster.).
2. [KubeConfigFileClient](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/java/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/io/kubernetes/client/examples/KubeConfigFileClientExample.java) Example: (Configure a client to access a Kubernetes cluster from outside.)

The first example from inside the cluster is using serviceaccount applied to the POD.

The second example from outside the cluster is using kubeconfig file.

In the official docs you can find java example of [Accessing Kubernetes API](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/access-cluster-api/#java-client) Using Java client I it uses kubeconfig file by default stored in `$HOME/.kube/config`. In addition you can find there other examples how to programmatically access the Kubernetes API with the list of [Officially-supported Kubernetes client libraries](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/client-libraries/) and [Community-maintained client libraries](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/client-libraries/#community-maintained-client-libraries)

Please refer also to the [Authorization Modes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authorization/#authorization-modules)

> Kubernetes RBAC allows admins to configure and control access to Kubernetes resources as well as the operations that can be performed on those resources.
>   RBAC can be enabled by starting the API server with --authorization-mode=RBAC
>
> Kubernetes includes a built-in role-based access control (RBAC) mechanism that allows you to configure fine-grained and specific sets of permissions that define how a given GCP user, or group of users, can interact with any Kubernetes object in your cluster, or in a specific Namespace of your cluster.

Additional resources:

- [Using RBAC Authorization](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/)
- [Accessing Clusters](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/access-cluster/)
- [Configure Service Accounts for Pods](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-service-account/)
- [Authorization Modes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authorization/#authorization-modules)
- [Kubernetes in Production](https://www.replex.io/blog/kubernetes-in-production)

Hope this help.

Comment: This link was helped to understand the authorization - https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/. Other stuff are useless and may be found on the first page of the google. Anyway, will accept the answer.